# Redirecting s3 cp logs into a single file using while loop and bash redirection is not working | multiple log files are getting created

Tags: bash, shell, redirect, logging

I am trying to save s3 cp command output to a single log file using bash shell script. My script takes the source and destination bucket information form another file called output.tsv which is actually inputs to a while loop. like below. I am using &>> to redirect the output to a file with the timestamp

```
while read SOURCE DESTINATION
do
    aws s3 cp $SOURCE $DESTINATION &>> /shared_data/logs/logs-$(date +"%b-%d-%Y-%H-%M-%Z").log
done < output.tsv
```

The s3 cp logs are supposed to be redirect/append to a single log file but What I see that the log files get created every single minute instead of redirecting it to a single file. FYI i am trying to copy bulk amount of files and my scripts runs for an hour.

`-rwxrwxr-- 1 user1 group1  33K Oct 28 06:13 logs-Oct-28-2021-06-12-PDT.log`

`-rwxrwxr-- 1 user1 group1  33K Oct 28 06:14 logs-Oct-28-2021-06-13-PDT.log`

`-rwxrwxr-- 1 user1 group1  53K Oct 28 06:15 logs-Oct-28-2021-06-14-PDT.log`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm not an AWS S3 user but) regarding your use case that just relates to a shell issue, you could just define the filename outside of your `while` loop:

```sh
log="/shared_data/logs/logs-$(date +"%b-%d-%Y-%H-%M-%Z").log"
while read SOURCE DESTINATION; do
    aws s3 cp "$SOURCE" "$DESTINATION" &>> "$log"
done < output.tsv
```

BTW, note that you might want to change your `date` format string to use a more standard ([ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) like) encoding:

```sh
log="/shared_data/logs/logs-$(date -u +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S").log"
```

The advantages of this `date` command being:

- the fact that lexicographically speaking, the string sorting order matches that of the dates;
- and uses the UTC timezone (thanks to [option `-u`](https://ss64.com/bash/date.html)):

```
$ date -u +"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S"
2021-10-28_16-42-00
```